# Insert a csv file as attachment in a pdf file JAVA

Tags: java, csv, pdf

I need to generate PDF which contains inside a CSV file as an attachment that can be opened (double clicking on it). Is there a way to do this programmaticaly in JAVA? Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't complete, and that complicates the answer (see my answer: I couldn't give *one* answer; I had to give several answers). In the future, please indicate which library you are using and which version of that library. Note that it is not allowed to ask people to recommend a library on Stack Overflow. Also be more specific about the type of attachment you want: do you want a document-level attachment or do you want a file attachment annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't show any code, it's hard to know whether you are using the new iText 7 or the old (and no longer supported) iText 5.

It is also unclear whether you want to attach as a document-level attachment (visible only in the attachment panel of the PDF) or  a file as an annotation (also visible on a page).

Let's assume that you're new at iText, and that you started with the most recent version. In that case, you can add a document-level attachment like this:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PdfFileSpec fs = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfDoc,
    PATH, null, "test.csv", null, null, false);
pdfDoc.addFileAttachment("specificname", fs);
```

In this case `PATH` is a file path to your CSV file.

The iText 7 code to add a file attachment annotation looks like this:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 700, 100, 100);
PdfFileSpec fs = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfDoc,
    PATH, null, "test.csv", null, null, false);
PdfAnnotation attachment = new PdfFileAttachmentAnnotation(rect, fs)
            .setContents("Click me");
pdfDoc.addNewPage().addAnnotation(attachment);
```

The rectangle `rect` defines the position and dimensions of the annotation. If you want to add a file attachment annotation to an existing document, you can create a `PdfDocument` that also takes a `PdfReader` instance as parameter.

If for some reason you still want to use the old iText, then you can add a document-level attachment like this:

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(
    writer, null, fileName, csv_stream;
fs.AddDescription("specificname", false);
writer.AddFileAttachment(fs);
```

Or like this:

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(
    writer, null, fileName, csv_stream);
fs.AddDescription("specificname", false);
stamper.AddFileAttachment(fs);
```

The former snippet is for when you have a `PdfWriter` instance because you're creating a document from scratch; the latter snippet is for when you have a `PdfStamper` instance because you're adding an attachment to an existing document.

For a file attachment annotation, you need this code:

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
    writer, null, fileName, csv_stream);
PdfAnnotation attachment =
    PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer, rect, fileName, fs);
writer.addAnnotation(attachment);
```

Or, if you don't have a `writer`, but a `stamper`:

```
stamper.addAnnotation(attachment, p);
```

where `p` is a page number.

Obviously, it's recommended to use iText 7 as that's more future-proof than iText 5.

Comment: Thanks very much Bruno. I am not using any version yet, I was asking about the technology needed to do this. I'm using iText as you proposed. Thanks again.